# Is a value an enum and -1?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

For view model validation, I need to determine whether a value, of which I only have an object interface, is an enum and has the numeric value of -1.

I tried this:

```
// object value;
if (value?.GetType().IsEnum == true && (int)value == -1) return null;
```

It should work with my Model enums which are mostly based on `int`.

But it fails when the value is a `Visibility` enum (that happens to be also in the view model class and should be ignored for validation) which is based on `byte` instead of `int` and that seems not to be castable to `int`. I could do some more testing but it shouldn't get too slow.

Is there a good simple solution for that? Maybe some test method in the `Enum` class or something?

Comment: Show the enums code.

Comment: byte cannot be equal to -1.

Comment: Maybe you need to base the enum on `sbyte` instead of `byte`.

Comment: I have created an enum based on byte & your code just produces warning of a possible invalid cast. Byte can be cast to int without any problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Visibility is a .net defined enum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the underlying type with [`GetEnumUnderlyingType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getenumunderlyingtype):

```
Type t = value?.GetType();
if (t?.IsEnum == true && 
    t?.GetEnumUnderlyingType() == typeof(int) && 
    (int)value == -1)
    return null;
```

Since a `byte` can never be `-1`, you don't need to check it. But you may need to extend the check for `long` enums, too.

---

**UPDATE**:

I just tried around a little and found that `Convert.ToInt32()` also solves your problem:

```
if (value?.GetType().IsEnum == true && 
    Convert.ToInt64(value) == -1)
    return null;
```

This seems cleaner and also works for all possible underlying types.

---

Another update: Unfortunatly the solution above is not as clean as I thought.  Even with `Convert.ToInt64()` solves the problem of `long` values too big for `Int32`, but it throws if you pass for example a `ulong.MaxValue`.

So you have to choose a type that is large enough for all possible enum base types:

```
if (value?.GetType().IsEnum == true && 
    Convert.ToDecimal(value) == -1)
    return null;
```

Using `Convert.ToDecimal()` this passes all the test cases that came up so far.

Comment: Take under consideration others as well, after [enum (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx): _The approved types for an enum are `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`._

Comment: In the second example, what happens if `enum MyEnum : long { MaxValue = long.MaxValue } }`, and then `value = MyEnum.MaxValue`? :-)

Comment: @xanatos damn right, `Convert.ToInt64()` could solve that, but will throw for `ulong.MaxValue`... I keep trying...

Comment: simple... if `OverflowException` is thrown for sure it is not `-1` ;) to be on the safe side i would simply put `Convert.ToInt32(value)` into `try-catch`

Comment: @gaa but exceptions are expensive, so I choose `Convert.ToDecimal()` to avoid the problem.

Comment: Or, as per your first idea, add a check for the underlying type not being unsigned int64.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, one could consider using the [Enum.IsDefined Method (Type, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify, if the value is a valid enum.

That does of course not cover the "check if it is -1" part.

> Enum.IsDefined Method (Type, Object)
>
> Returns an indication whether a constant with a specified value exists
>   in a specified enumeration. Namespace:    System Assembly:  mscorlib
>   (in mscorlib.dll)
>
> ```
> [ComVisibleAttribute(true)] public static bool IsDefined( Type enumType, object value )
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `enumTypeType`: `System.Type` 
>   An enumeration type.
>   `valueType`: `System.Object` The value or name of a constant in enumType.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> `Type`: `System.Boolean` becomes `true` if a constant in enumType has a
>   value equal to value; otherwise, `false`.
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> `ArgumentNullException' enumType or value is null.`
>   ArgumentException` enumType is not an Enum. -or-  The type of value is an enumeration, but it is not an enumeration of type enumType. -or- The type of value is not an underlying type of enumType.
>
> `InvalidOperationException` value is not type SByte, Int16, Int32, Int64, Byte, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, or String.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The value parameter can be any of the following:
>
> - Any member of type enumType.
> - A variable whose value is an enumeration member of type enumType.
> - The string representation of the name of an enumeration member. The
>     characters in the string must have the same case as the enumeration
>     member name.
> - A value of the underlying type of enumType.
>
> If the constants in enumType define a set of bit fields and value
>   contains the values, names, or underlying values of multiple bit
>   fields, the IsDefined method returns false. In other words, **for
>   enumerations that define a set of bit fields, the method determines
>   only whether a single bit field belongs to the enumeration.** To
>   determine whether multiple bit fields are set in an enumeration type
>   that is tagged with the FlagsAttribute attribute, you can call the
>   HasFlag method.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
if (value != null)
{
    var type = value.GetType();

    if (type.IsEnum && object.Equals(Enum.ToObject(type, -1), value))
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had to do it in multiple lines to "cache" the `GetType()`. The trick is using `Enum.ToObject()` to "cast" `-1` to the current `Enum` type.

Note that casting will generate "strange" results:

```
public enum TestEnum : ulong
{
    ValueMax = ulong.MaxValue
}
```

In this case, `TestEnum.ValueMax` will `return null`. This will happen for all the unsigned types.

Answer (score 0):

`byte` can be casted to `int` if it is not boxed with `object`

```
byte b = 1;
int i = (int)b; //works good
int f = (int)(object)b; //fails
```

So you could convert your variable to `int` using `Convert.ToInt32` method, as René Vogt suggested, or cast it to `dynamic` instead casting to `int`:

```
if (value?.GetType().IsEnum == true && (dynamic)value == -1) return null;
```

Although, operations with `dynamic` are rather slow. In my opinion, soultion with `Convert.ToInt32` is the most cleanable and efficient. This answer is just to point out, why you can not cast the `object` to `int` and suggest a `dynamic` version of cast.